# Issue of hosting on godaddy for CodeIgniter 3?

Tags: codeigniter

I have an issue with godaddy hosting my site using CodeIgniter 3, its working for main homepage, but when I clicked on links it need like `www.example.com/index.php/submodule/subdir`,

I don't understand how can I solve it and use it like `www.example.com/sumodule/subdir`

I'm using this HTACCESS file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $l !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$l [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28682210/how-to-remove-index-php-with-codeigniter-in-godaddy-com#answer-28682743) if is helpful for you.

Comment: If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this variable so that it is blank.|

$config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: Make sure you have place the htaccess outside of the main application folder.

Comment: yeah i placed it outside.. and m used mod_rewrite  but its not working on CI3

Comment: I checked that link Tpojka still no changes.. i need to use index.php in URL

Answer (score 1):

Use this in `.htaccess` file and `.htaccess` file must be outside codeigniter `application` folder

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?/$1
```

Comment: i placed it... its working fine with base url but not for like www.example.com/submodule/subcontrollers.. still i need to place it like www.example.com/index.php/submodule/subcontrollers

Comment: also i set all config variables properly..like index is empty.. and Uri is AUto

Comment: Are you use HMVC in codeigniter structure or something else?

Comment: and i did some research and I noted one point.. my client is using Plesk windows hosting.. when i searched for it.. one person said this was the prob,, and he changed it s plan to cpanel linux hosting and prob solved,, but i can not able to do that,,,